# MVVM implement ICommand in .NET 4.5

Tags: mvvm, .net-4.5

Is there a strongly-typed implementation of ICommand in .NET 4.5?  If so where does it live?  I've seen a number of implementations of DelegateCommand floating around on blogs but didn't know if there is an official implementation rolled into the base class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no strongly typed implementation of ICommand in the BCL. [If you are using MVVM, then you should be using an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). Commanding has limitations anyway, so I would recommend looking at something like [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)'s Actions.

Comment: Yes, RoutedCommand is not that great... I only mentioned it for the sake of accuracy.